# a tutorial to import & export excel file

Tags: c#, excel, windows-phone-8

A list of students should be imported in my windows phone 8 application. i made some research and found example, but it doesn't work for me:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (store.FileExists("services.txt"))
{
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("services.txt", FileMode.Open, store))
    {
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
string[] tmp = result.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n', '.' });
foreach (string str in tmp)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: what doesn't work in your example?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? there is an input example, wanted output?